# How to get last line executed by a generator in Python

Tags: python, generator

I am trying to get number of last line that has been executed by a generator in Python. I find a ways to get it in several cases:

- generator suspended by `yield`,
- generator failed with an exception (not the `StopIteration`),
- generator returned by **explicit** raising of the `StopIteration`.

But I am asking for an advice about how to get the line number in case of the `StopIteration` is raised automatically after the generator executed `return` statement or just reached last line of corresponding function.

A simplified code example I used is listed below.

```
from sys import exc_info

def gen1():
    print("1.1")
    yield
    print("1.2")
    raise StopIteration()

def gen2():
    print("2.1")
    yield
    print("2.2")
    return

def gen3():
    print("3.1")
    yield
    print("3.2")
    raise RuntimeError()

for gen in [ g for n, g in globals().items() if n.startswith("gen") ]:
    g = gen() # launch the generator
    while True:
        try:
            next(g)
        except StopIteration: # generator normally returned
            tb = exc_info()[2].tb_next
            if tb is None:
                print("How to get last line?")
            else:
                print("last line: %s" % tb.tb_frame.f_lineno)
            break
        except BaseException: # generator failure
            tb = exc_info()[2].tb_next
            print("last line: %s" % tb.tb_frame.f_lineno)
            break
        else:
            print("last line: %s" % g.gi_frame.f_lineno)
```

Execution of this code returns:

```
3.1
last line: 17
3.2
last line: 19
2.1
last line: 11
2.2
How to get last line?
1.1
last line: 5
1.2
last line: 7
```

Comment: What is the problem you are _really_ solving? Why are you interested in the line numbers?

Comment: The information you're looking for no longer exists. The frame has already been released and therefore garbage collected because the function has returned (and `gi_frame` has been set to `None`). The traceback didn't copy anything from the frame when it was created, because it comes from the generator machinery after the function returned, not from inside the function.

Comment: @9000, I am measuring time between `yield`s and notify a developer if it is too long. But if the function have several `return`s I have the trouble with pointing to the last executed code interval.

Comment: How are you driving the generator in your real code? If you're taking a generator function, and creating the generator and driving it to the end, as in this example code, I think you can do it, as shown in my answer. But if, say, you're trying to hook every generator creation, keeping all the frames alive could be a terrible idea (imagine the leak if someone ran an `asyncio` loop and you kept alive every frame of every coroutine created until the runloop ends…).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The information you want is in the frame object.

But the frame object has already been garbage collected. The reference to it in `g.gi_frame` is set to `None` when the function returns.

The traceback won't help you, because the traceback comes from the machinery inside the interpreter after the function has returned, so it has nowhere to get it (and you've already seen that it doesn't even try).

---

But if you can change your code to grab a reference to the `gi_frame` object while the generator is running and hold onto it after it finishes, you'll keep that—and all of the other associated garbage—alive.

Which means `f_lineno` may be valid, as used in your last case that never happens. I don't know if there's any way to check when `f_lineno` is and isn't meaningful, but the traceback-generating code might know that if you dive into its source.

If not, `f_lasti` will definitely be the bytecode offset of the `RETURN_VALUE` op. Python of course doesn't guarantee anywhere that it doesn't do anything funky with the `lasti` before releasing the frame, but it doesn't in any version yet, and it's hard to see what reason there would be to do so in the future. So it should always be correct to use the information in `f_code.co_lnotab` to generate the line number for `f_lasti`. See the `dis` module for help on that. (If your Python is new enough, it exposes a `findlinestarts` that does it for you; if not, read the source of the module. Or write your own lnotab parser from the docs in the `Objects` directory of the interpreter source, if you want some real fun.)

Comment: I modified the code in the question to keep reference to `gi_frame`, thank you. Modifications are:

1) add `gi_frame = g.gi_frame` after `g = gen()`,
2) change `print("How to get last line?")` to `print("last line: %s" % gi_frame.f_lineno)`

Comment: @VasilyE. Yes. But as I said, I'm not sure `f_lineno` will always be valid there. If you're planning on using this in a tool you give to other developers, not just experimenting for fun, you really need to either (a) read through the source to make sure it's always correct, (b) unit test the hell out of it, or (c) look up `f_lasti` in `dis.findlinestarts` instead.

Comment: I checked it on a function with several `return`s and it always points to one that is actually was executed. If I will meet a problem with this approach then I will investigate it deeply. In real code I have a descriptor for each generator I interested in. I do not hook any generator creation. Only specific generators are controlled.